# Xamarin android getting all the views from a recyclerview using getChildAt - not displaying all rows, only those on show

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I am banging my head against a wall, using Xamarin.Android c#

I have a Recycler view which recycles a simple list which contains a TextView and an EditText.

I am reading a list of 9 items and displaying these correctly, when I update the editText values these are being saved in the correct position - so again all good so far.

I am new to using RecyclerView and my issue is that when I want to loop through all 9 rows in the list to return the view at each position I am using **RecyclerView.GetChildAt(position).**

This only appears to loop through the 7 line items in the list that were on display at the point in time that I hit the submit button.

The idea is that if the EditText values are changed on any of the list view lines, that value is taken and updated in a sql db record that matches the line data for the row/view.

If I use **RecyclerView.GetAdapter().ItemCount** - I am returning the correct 9 items which need to be looped through but when I get to position 8 and 9 the view is returned as a null value and I am guessing this is because the view for those line items wasn't on display in the Recycler view at the point of submission button tap.

My simply question is, how to I ensure or retrieve all the line item values from my recyclerview or from the listview that is contained within my recyclerview as I need to get all the lines not just those on display.

Here is some of my code:

```
public class RecycleAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public IList<WebService.LineList> pickLineList;

    public RecycleAdapter(IList<WebService.LineList> pickLineDetailList)
    {
        pickLineList = pickLineDetailList;
    }

    public class PickViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View pickMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView itemId { get; set; }
        public TextView itemDetails { get; set; }
        public TextView transferQty { get; set; }
        public TextView stockUnit { get; set; }
        public TextView lineNum { get; set; }
        public EditText pickedQty { get; set; }

        public CheckBox fullQty { get; set; }
        public CheckBox cancelQty { get; set; }
        public TextView itemPosition { get; set; }

        public PickViewHolder(View view) : base(view)
        {
            pickMainView = view;
        }
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.pickLineListviewLayout,parent,false);

        TextView itemId = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pickItemId);
        TextView itemDetails = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pickItemDetails);
        TextView transferQty = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pickTransferQty);
        TextView stockUnit = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pickUnitId);
        TextView lineNum = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pickLineNum);
        EditText pickedQty = row.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.pickNowQty);
        CheckBox fullQty = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.FullPickLine);
        CheckBox cancelQty = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.CancelPickLine);
        TextView itemPosition = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pickLineRecId);

        // initalise the values from the recycled view into the viewholder 
        PickViewHolder pickView = new PickViewHolder(row)
        {
            itemId = itemId,
            itemDetails = itemDetails,
            transferQty = transferQty,
            stockUnit = stockUnit,
            lineNum = lineNum,
            pickedQty = pickedQty,
            cancelQty = cancelQty,
            itemPosition = itemPosition,
            fullQty = fullQty
        };

        return pickView;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PickViewHolder pickHolder = holder as PickViewHolder;

        pickHolder.itemId.Text = pickLineList[position].parmItemId;
        pickHolder.itemDetails.Text = pickLineList[position].parmItemDesc;
        pickHolder.itemPosition.Text = pickLineList[position].parmRecId.ToString();
        pickHolder.transferQty.Text = pickLineList[position].parmTransQty.ToString();
        pickHolder.stockUnit.Text = pickLineList[position].parmUnitId;
        pickHolder.lineNum.Text = (position + 1).ToString();

        // if Full pick is checked on the line then populate the pickNowQty with full transaction Qty
        if (pickHolder.fullQty != null) //Verify the state of your whatever object to avoid exception
        {
            pickHolder.fullQty.CheckedChange += (object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (e.IsChecked)
                {
                    pickHolder.pickedQty.Text = pickLineList[position].parmTransQty.ToString();                        
                }
                else
                {
                    pickHolder.pickedQty.Text = "";
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public override int ItemCount 
    {
        get { return pickLineList.Count; }
    }
}
```

Code for submit button logic:

```
private void SubmitPickLinesBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BM_PickLineUpdateRequestContract[] updateLineList = new BM_PickLineUpdateRequestContract[pickRecyclerView.GetAdapter().ItemCount];

        for (int i = 1; i <= pickRecyclerView.GetAdapter().ItemCount; i++)
        {
            // create map list of recordId and picked order line qty to be passed 
            BM_PickLineUpdateRequestContract updateLineContract = new BM_PickLineUpdateRequestContract();

            // get the position in the listview matching the dataset
            View rowView = pickRecyclerView.GetChildAt(i);

            if (rowView != null)
            {
                EditText qtyNow = rowView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.pickNowQty);
```

The issue I have from above is that my rowView value is NULL for the 2 line items that are not on display or part of the recyclerview when I tap submit button and logic is envoked. - I need to be able to get all the view lines on the list and read the data from them

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

> My simply question is, how to I ensure or retrieve all the line item
> values from my recyclerview or from the listview that is contained
> within my recyclerview as I need to get all the lines not just those
> on display.

Do you want to get all the data binded to the `recyclerview` , right?

Then you can retrieve the datalist which is passed to the constructor of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` for your `Recyclerview`  .

```
public class PhotoAlbumAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public static List<Item> mPhotoAlbum = new List<Item>();

    public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<Item> branchesList)
    {
        adapter = this;
        mPhotoAlbum = branchesList;
    }

    // other code

 }

   // here we define a global variable `items`
   List<Item> items= new List<Item>();
   PhotoAlbumAdapter mAdapter;
   RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

   mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(items);
   mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here,we can get all the datalist like this:

```
   resultBtn.Click += delegate {
    // we can loop through `items` to get all the data
            for (int i=0;i< items.Count;i++) {
                Item temp = items[i];
            }
    };
```

#### Update :

> when I scroll or the view is recycled, the values I entered in the
> edit text are now appearing in the incorrect row (view)

For your requirement, we usually use `ITextWatcher` to achieve this.

And we usually add `TextWatcher` in our `ViewHolder` to avoid the  incorrect data display.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class PhotoViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
    public TextView Caption { get; private set; }
    public CheckBox MyCheckBox { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }


    public Button DeleteButton { get; set; }

    public EditText MyEditText { get; set; }


     public MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher;

    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener, MyTextWatcher myWatcher  ) : base(itemView)
    {
        //Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView);
        Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        MyCheckBox = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.myCheckBox);

        DeleteButton = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.deleteBtn);

        MyEditText = itemView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.mEditText);

        this.myTextWatcher = myWatcher;


        MyEditText.AddTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);

        // Detect user clicks on the item view and report which item
        // was clicked (by layout position) to the listener:
        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.LayoutPosition);

        MyCheckBox.Click += delegate
        {
            if (MyCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I can get the adapter position here {0}", AdapterPosition);
                IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I can get the adapter position here {0}", AdapterPosition);
                IsChecked = false;
            }
        };
    }


    public class MyTextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
    {
        int position;


        public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
        {
        }

        public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            PhotoAlbumAdapter.mPhotoAlbum[position].mInput = s.ToString();
        }

        public void updatePosition(int position)
        {
            this.position = position;
        }

    }
}
```

And `OnBindViewHolder` method :

```
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
        //***********************
        Photo item=   mPhotoAlbum[position];

        vh.Caption.Text = item.Caption;

        vh.MyCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        vh.MyCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyListener(item));
        vh.MyCheckBox.Checked = item.isChecked;

        vh.myTextWatcher.updatePosition(vh.AdapterPosition);

        vh.MyEditText.Text = item.mInput;

        vh.DeleteButton.SetOnClickListener(new MyRemoveItem(item,position));

    }
```

**Note:**

`photo.isChecked`  is a property of the Item(mine is `Photo`) in `Recyclerview`.

```
public class Photo
{
    public string mCaption;
    // other code

    public string mInput { get; set; }

    public bool isChecked {  get; set; }

}
```

And the `PhotoAlbumAdapter.mPhotoAlbum` in `MyTextWatcher.cs` is the data list in my `RecyclerView.Adapter`, the prefix is `public static`:

```
public static List<Photo> mPhotoAlbum = new List<Photo>();
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I have this logic in place as you have above, that is not the problem, my issue is referencing the view on each line of the list so I can get the EDITTEXT value as this is an input from the user - I get the logic that if I use RecyclerView.GetChildAt(position) to get my view and therefore the EDITTEXT value associated with this view I only get the views on display for that instance of the recyclerview - I need to be able to get all lines or view lines that are available - your answer isn't explaining this, only referring to the original data list - still need more on this

Comment: I have updated my answer. It works on my side.  You can check it up .

Comment: Hi Jessie, Thanks again - is there an example for handling the checkbox? it is just when I tick the FULL PICK checkbox, it is now adding the edit text value in the incorrect row in the list, I had this working correctly before adding in the text watcher

Comment: Hi @Christy, please check my updated answer.  :)

Comment: Hi Jessie, this is excellent and makes sense but now what is happening is when I scroll or the view is recycled, the values I entered in the edit text are now appearing in the incorrect row (view) - I need a simple example or I need it pointed out in my code where I am going wrong Thanks

Comment: Sorry  Christy,  to address this issue, I have updated the answer. And it works on my side .

Comment: Hi @Christy,may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is technically impossible. It is called 'Recycler' exactly because it uses just limited number of views to display data, so once the item is not on the display its view is 'recycled' for a new item that becomes visible.

You can't pull the view that doesn't exist.

You need to have a data model where you store and pull the data from, and I think providing the code for that is a bit out of scope of StackOverflow, though it would be great if someone is willing to put that effort.

Comment: Hi Ivan Thank you for confirming this - so in effect I need a data model or class containing a list of the values I need to update and when the edit text is changed or a checkbox is checked I should be updating the correct record in this list or data model, then re-use it later on?

Comment: @Christy yes, there are multiple possible ways to do that but in general you need to store it somewhere and recall it from there. Possibly you can use and extend adapter for that. Or make a completely new class. Depends on what you want to achieve.